# How to provide a list of artifacts to the maven-dependency-plugin:copy goal through a variable?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to do this:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <my-artifacts>org.junit:junit,org.slf4j:slf4j</my-artifacts>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                ${my-artifacts}
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you want to copy and for what purpose? Maybe a different Maven goal suits your use case better.

Comment: I want to load some artifacts, while the list of them I have in the Maven property :)

Comment: Can you give more details in which way you want to "load some artifacts" ? In which context? CI? Console?

Comment: @yegor256 that is what you already said. But maybe, with a bit more background, it would be easier to find a solution. Because normally, you manage everything through Maven dependencies, and not lists in a property.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I want my plugin to create a list of artifacts to copy, and then `maven-dependency-plugin` will copy them

Answer (score 1):

First you have to configure the artifactItems because artifactItems means there are several of them. To define a single artifact you have to define artifactItem as part of the list...like the following:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
                  <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
                  <version>[ version ]</version>
                  <type>[ packaging ]</type>
                  <classifier> [classifier - optional] </classifier>
                  <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>[ output directory ]</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>[ filename ]</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <!-- other configurations here -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

You can not define a list of artifact via a property. You have to define them in the configuration. You could define a single artifact via a property if you change your configuration according to the above.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:copy